# Copy values from a file to a new file only after certain characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a file with the following format:

```
Reading frame    3000 time 30000.000   ^MReading frame    3000 time 30000.000   mu  8.788e+00 <mu>  2.945e-03
```

and I want to paste the values which are ONLY after mu in a new file which will have the following desire output:

```
8.788e+00
```

I tried the below command but without success

```
grep "mu" filename1 | sed 's/^.* //' > filename2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "mu")print $(i+1)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -E 's/.*mu +([0-9.e+-]+) .*/\1/p' file
```

The regex expect the string `mu` and the number to be together.

Comment: super!!! this works just perfectly !!!!!!